# Counting rows from a GROUP BY query using an index

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I'm using **sqlite 3.8.2** and I want to count the row from that query:

```
    SELECT artist
      FROM media
  GROUP BY artist
```

**Note:** that query is quite fast because it's using a index `media_idx_14` on the `artist` column

So the query that I need is:

```
  SELECT count (*) 
    FROM (
        SELECT artist
          FROM media
      GROUP BY artist
    )
```

The issue is that this query doesn't perform as fast as it should.

Here's the query plan:

```
SCAN TABLE media USING INDEX media_idx_14 
SCAN SUBQUERY 1
```

My query does a table SCAN while all the info it needs is already in the index.

**Is there a way to improve my query to get rid of the inefficient table SCAN?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend trying this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT artist)
FROM media
```

Comment: Simple and efficient. Thank you!